# loading data into a datagrid with Anonymous Type

Tags: wpf, silverlight, linq, entity-framework

Here is what is going on. If I bind the following to a datagrid

```
var myQ = myDataContext.MyEntity1.Where(e1 => e1.ID == aNum);
datagrid1.ItemSource = myQ
```

I could see the data in the datagrid.

But if I do

```
var myQ = myDataContext.MyEntity1.Join(myDataContext.MyEntity2, e1=>e1.ID, e2 =>e2.ID, (e1,e2) =>new {e1.something, e2.something};
datagrid1.ItemSource = myQ;
```

The datagrid could not be loaded with data. Why? anything to do with asynchronous? Then why would .Where work and .Join would not then? What should I call to update the datagrid to get it loaded?

Comment: is it because you are using myEntity1 instead of MyEntity1?

Comment: No, just a typo in the post. already changed it....

Comment: Try to force it ToList() and see if the Join has any elements.

Comment: Thanks..The list has no elements.... But I tested the same join statement in the database with SQL. It was fine.... So it is the query that returns nothing then?

Comment: Apparently yes. Is this another typo : e2 =>e2,ID ?

Comment: yes, it was a typo. I used VS 2010 so no typos in my program,:)) Thanks.

Comment: Apparently you need to review your query, nothing to do with WPF dataBindng

Comment: I think it is the code. Even the simple joins are not working. It seems like the datagrid is not reloading... Do I need something like loadOP.Completed += to make it reload the data?

Comment: @NewDTinStackoverflow If a ToList() results in a `Sequence contains no elements` than you're not retrieving any data from the database. What is your sql query?

Comment: true. But I have not find anything wrong with my query yet. here is my sql query: select E1.Field1, E2.Field2 from E1 inner join E2 on E1.id = E2.id It returns exactly what I want.

Comment: If it is possible than use the approach presented by @LuisSánchez It is more readable in my opinion. Are you also sure about the join on ID's from both entities? Just asking.

Comment: I did. And the list was populated but no data in the datagrid.....

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a diff approach?

```
var myQ =  (from a in myDataContext.E1
            join b in myDataContext.E2 on a.id equals b.id
            select new {a.something, b.something}).ToList();
datagrid1.ItemSource = myQ;
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

```
var myQ =  (from a in myDataContext.E1
            join b in myDataContext.E2 on a.id equals b.id
            select a).ToList();
datagrid1.ItemSource = myQ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it with 2 different entities. still no data in the datagrid. But the list thing does have 2 elements in it.... So it is a display problem....

Comment: Try something. Check my update. I wanna see if the problem is with the render of the grid, we're not passing a parameter in my edited solution, we're passing the entire object, if that works, then the problem could be that the grid is not able to display an object with those 2 parameters.

Comment: Thanks. That code ran fine when a is selected. Everything was displayed as it should.

Comment: Great, then you should create a model view that contains the values you want to show on the grid!

Comment: But why the first one could not be displayed? I just don't understand...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already used this tool, I suggest [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It will help you see exactly what the output of your Linq statement is, and you can also see the precise SQL the Linq query generates. Use this to test your Linq quickly and painlessly.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!